# Call a custom function passing input into function argument Shiny

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny

I want to pass an input as an argument in Shiny, so that I can pull the necessary file based on user choice. Is this possible or do I have to join the files before running the app? The function is the MyFunction below in the subset data section.

```
library(shiny)


ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Title"),

  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(position = "left",
             selectInput(inputId = "competitor",
                         label = h3("Competitor:"), 
                         choices = unique(Grouped$variable1),
                         selected = "1"),

              selectInput(inputId = "state",
                        label = h3("State:"), 
                        choices = c("IA","MA","PA","CA","MD","TN"),
                        selected = "CA")),

mainPanel(plotOutput(outputId = "lineplot", height = "400px"))
  )
)


server <- function(input, output) {

  # Subset data
  reactive({
    MyFunction(input$state)})  

  selected_company <- reactive({
    Grouped %>%
      filter(Variable2 == input$competitor)})

  output$lineplot <- renderPlot({
    ggplot(selected_company(),aes(x=Month, y=Rate)) +
      geom_bar(stat="identity",fill="blue") +
      theme_classic()

    })
}

# Create Shiny object
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Essentially, I am pulling a file by state. And then I am manipulating that file to show specific metrics in graphical form in the app, with the addition of a user selecting what "competitor" they wish to see.

I'd give you the full function, but considering the proprietary nature of many of the variables, it likely is not worth the time to re-format to get rid of these, as it is a long function. The function works fine on it's own however.

The problem is on the Shiny end trying to pass in a function based on a reactive input.

Comment: shouldnt this `reactive({MyFunction(input$state)})` be some variable such as `state <- reactive({MyFunction(input$state)})`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to rerun the function whenever `input$state` changes, use

```
observe({MyFunction(req(input$state))})})
```

The `req` part makes sure the input is available (not `NULL`) before passing it to the function. The way you coded it, i.e.

```
reactive({MyFunction(input$state)})
```

the function will never be run since there are no observers for the reactive created. About joining files: You can just `source` the file where the function is defined like this

```
# app.R
source("path/to/my_function/definition.R")

shinyApp(
  ...
)
```